# renderIntoDocument clean up after test

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking at the [React Test Utilities docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html), in particular at the `renderIntoDocument` function:

> Render a component into a detached DOM node in the document.

I am wondering whether I should be doing anything with the component that I've rendered once I'm done testing?

This works:

```
const component = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(createElement(MyThing));

// do tests

unmountComponentAtNode(findDOMNode(component).parentElement);
```

but I'm wondering if this step is necessary, since it isn't mentioned in the docs. Does my current approach actually achieve anything useful, or can I just use `renderIntoDocument` without worrying about tidying up?